# psycopg2 set proper encoding

Tags: python, character-encoding, psycopg2

I am using `psycopg2` as database adapter.
The connection looks like

```
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host=hostname,  user=username,  password=password,  dbname=database  )
```

In the result of my query i have rows containing  text like `"РќР• РўР\xa0Р•Р‘РЈР•РўРЎРЇ"`.
It's russian and it seems it's not properly encoded.
I tried different encodings like `latin1, windows-1251`  and have errors like

```
 codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(256)
```

How to properly encode / decode such text ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably in choosing the right encoding.

Try using the **chardet** library to automatically detect the encoding of the byte string.

Sample code:

```
import chardet

# Assuming `byte_string` is the byte string you are trying to decode
detected_encoding = chardet.detect(byte_string)['encoding']
decoded_string = byte_string.decode(detected_encoding)
```

Also, I hope you are using the *client_encoding* parameter to use the right encoding for your connection.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(
       host='your_host',
       port=5439,
       dbname='your_database',
       user='your_username',
       password='your_password',
       client_encoding='utf8'
       )
```